# Where are In-App Purchase downloads hosted?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Using a comic app (like the Marvel app) as an example, where is a comic book purchased via an In-App Purchase actually hosted (as in where does it download from)? Is it on Apple servers (like the app itself is) or on the app developers servers?

I ask because Apple charges 30% for an In-App Purchase...the same as they do for a regular app purchase. This is supposed to be in exchange for things like not paying credit card processing fees and not having to host the app ourselves. But in the case of an In-App Purchase that requires a download (and not simply unlocking a feature already contained within the app), I assume the download has to come from the app developers own servers...which means the app developer is paying for the data transfer on top of the 30% to Apple. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Eddie

Comment: Not sure why this is "off topic". As Apple doesn't host the purchased file, then some development is involved, both on the app end to download the file(s) and the file hosting itself. As a developer looking into In-App Purchase options, this question was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not host content outside of your ipa file. You can use services like Urban Airship to help. Again, they take a small cut for their service, but it definitely makes it easier than setting up your own S3/webservices.

http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/